# Send data to FancyBox in php

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, modal-dialog, fancybox

I need to pass a value to a modal window (fancybox). To do this I created the following code:

```
$.fancybox.open({
    type: 'iframe', // ajax but switched to iframe for testing
    href: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/aggiungiFarmaci_controller',
    maxWidth: 800,
    maxHeight: 600,
    fitToView: false,
    autoSize: true,
    closeClick: false,
    autoCenter: true,
    scrolling: 'no',
    padding: 0,
    ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        data: $("#formCF").serialize(),
    },
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            closeClick: false,
            css: {
                'background': 'rgba(150,144,146,.60)'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

The page I want to open and populate with the value passed by the caller of the modal window has the following code:

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->helper((array('form')));
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $data = array('aic' => $this->input->post('codiceFarmaco'));
    $this->load->view('aggiungiFarmaci_view',$data);
}
```

Unfortunately I can not pass the parameter I wanted (AIC Code) to the modal window that opens without showing it. How can I fix? I think the problem lies in the code that calls fancybox, but I do not know what else to try. Thank you so much for the help

Comment: why you don't try the other way around? Make the ajax call first and call fancybox from within the ajax's `success` with the returned response.

Comment: Can you give me a concrete example? Thanks

Comment: One question first: where is the selector `#formCF`? in your parent page or in the ajaxed page? if in parent page, I assume you may want to pass `data` after the form `submit`, don't you?

Comment: Traduzione
The ajax code is executed upon the occurrence of an event that I have not shown here. I want to send data to the page that I open in fancybox, help me :)

Comment: You didn't answer my question (where is the selector `#formCF`?) so I don't want to post a "guessing" answer

Comment: Sorry, #formCF is added to the page where the script ajax you see in the post, is a form that has the task of recording the information in a database.The script Ajax has the task of taking one of the fields of the parent form (I read them all with serialize () ) and pre-load a text field on the page that will open fancybox.
In a nutshell, the parent page to pass information to the page that will show you the daughter formatting them in the appropriate text fields can not be changed.
I have been clearer? Thank you and I apologize for my previous lack of clarity.